# How to access a Oracle function(with default parameters) using Hibernate?

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I have my function defined as below in an Oracle 10g database that returns a `ref_cursor` and the input param has a default value of 2

```
FUNCTION fn_get_client(pv_clientId_len_i IN NUMBER DEFAULT 2)
    RETURN gtyp_ref_cur;
```

Here is how I am calling the function from hibernate - contents of the hibernate mapping file

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.synapsegroupinc.services.crm.ExplainLanguageService.model">
    <class name="ClientInfo" schema="IVR">      
        <id name="clientId" column="client_id" type="string" />
        <property name="clientDesc" column="client_desc" type="string" />        
    </class>
   <sql-query name="FN_GET_CLIENT" callable="true">
        <return class="ClientInfo">
            <return-property name="clientId" column="client_id"/>
            <return-property name="clientDesc" column="client_desc" />         
        </return>
        { ? = call PKG_CAMS_IVR_CRM.FN_GET_CLIENT(?) }
    </sql-query>  
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Problem**: everything works fine when I pass an input value when calling the function. However, I need to be able to make it work so that when I call the function with no input so the default value should be used.

I did lot of googling but no luck as to whether hibernate can support default parameters or not when calling function/stored procedure.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's a bug? What kind of jdbc drivers are you using? Did you check if are the right ones?

By the way, did you try to override the `fn_get_client` and remove the parameter? Then with this function you can make a call to the function that accepts one parameter with the default option. It could work...